# Why is this interpreted as a dynamic array, in Cosmos PatchItemAsync

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have this code:

```cs
public async Task Patch(Guid id, string patchPath, dynamic itemValue, PK pk)
        {
            try
            {
                await this._cosmosContainer.PatchItemAsync<T>(
                    id: id.ToString(),
                    partitionKey: new PartitionKey(pk.ToString()),
                    patchOperations: new[] {
                        PatchOperation.Replace<dynamic>(patchPath, itemValue)
                    });
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Which shows the following error:

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'dynamic[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PatchOperation>'

My question is, why doesn't it interpret the type correctly. The type that `patchOperations` receives is `IReadOnlyList<PatchOperation>`. So if I just change the array type to `new PatchOperation[]` it stops showing an error.

```cs
public async Task Patch(Guid id, string patchPath, dynamic itemValue, PK pk)
        {
            try
            {
                await this._cosmosContainer.PatchItemAsync<T>(
                    id: id.ToString(),
                    partitionKey: new PartitionKey(pk.ToString()),
                    patchOperations: new PatchOperation[] {
                        PatchOperation.Replace<dynamic>(patchPath, itemValue)
                    });
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call of the generic method `.Replace<dynamic>()` leads to the result being also of type `dynamic` and because you put it into an implict typed array it ends up being a `dynamic[]`. By adding the explicit type to the `new` operator you *leave the dynamic world* and come back to explicit types (if the cast at runtime succeeds).

So `dynamic` has at this point a similar behaviour to `async/await`. Once you enter its world you have to use it *all the way up* or explicitly leave it.

#### Update

Just to show, that once you enter *dynamic* everything will be *dynamic* take a look at this example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic value = new object();
        var result = DoSomething(value);
    }

    private static MyResult DoSomething<T>(T value)
    {
        return new MyResult();
    }
}

public class MyResult
{

}
```

If you inspect the type of `var result` in the above example, you'll see it is `dynamic`.

Comment: But why is the result also of type `dynamic`? In the docs the return type is `PatchOperation` so shouldn't it still be a `PatchOperation[]` with one element that has a dynamic value?

Comment: Thank you for the simple example. Had no idea that it worked like that!